# install.php is not being run during installation

Tags: socialengine

My install.php is not being run during installation.I checked everywhere.To be sure,I ran the code in install.php elsewhere and it worked well. But during installation only the install.php is being skipped somehow.My module name is Hotelreservation, hence the code in install.php is as below. Why is there no error display during installation ?

```
<?php

class Hotelreservation_Installer extends Engine_Package_Installer_Module
{
  public function onInstall()
  {
    $this->_hotelroomsBrowsePage();

    parent::onInstall();

  }

  protected function _hotelroomsBrowsePage()
  {
    $db = $this->getDb();

    // profile page
    $page_id = $db->select()
      ->from('engine4_core_pages', 'page_id')
      ->where('name = ?', 'hotelreservation_index_browse')
      ->limit(1)
      ->query()
      ->fetchColumn();

    if (!$page_id) {
      // Insert page
      $db->insert('engine4_core_pages', array(
        'name' => 'hotelreservation_index_browse',
        'displayname' => 'HotelRooms Browse Page',
        'title' => 'Browse Rooms',
        'description' => 'this page displays rooms',
        'custom' => 0,
      ));
      $page_id = $db->lastInsertId();

     // Insert main
      $db->insert('engine4_core_content', array(
        'type' => 'container',
        'name' => 'main',
        'page_id' => $page_id,
      ));
      $main_id = $db->lastInsertId();

      // Insert middle
      $db->insert('engine4_core_content', array(
        'type' => 'container',
        'name' => 'middle',
        'page_id' => $page_id,
        'parent_content_id' => $main_id,
        'order' => 2,
      ));
      $middle_id = $db->lastInsertId();

      // Insert hotelreservation.browse-menu
      $db->insert('engine4_core_content', array(
        'type' => 'widget',
        'name' => 'hotelreservation.browse-menu',
        'page_id' => $page_id,
        'parent_content_id' => $middle_id,
        'order' => 1,
      ));

      // Insert core content
      $db->insert('engine4_core_content', array(
        'type' => 'widget',
        'name' => 'core.content',
        'page_id' => $page_id,
        'parent_content_id' => $middle_id,
        'order' => 2,
      ));

      // Insert left
      $db->insert('engine4_core_content', array(
        'type' => 'container',
        'name' => 'left',
        'page_id' => $page_id,
        'parent_content_id' => $main_id,
        'order' => 3,
      ));
      $left_id = $db->lastInsertId();

    }

    return $this;
  }



}// end class
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you **`add info to mainfest file`** like this in **`packages array`**

```
'callback' => array(
  'path' => 'Your path to php file',
  'class' => 'Hotelreservation_Installer',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Arif. Check the file manifest.php inside of //settings:

(info of module Album)

```
    'callback' => array(
          'path' => 'application/modules/Album/settings/install.php',
          'class' => 'Album_Installer',
     ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and got it to work.
It turns out that the installer looks in application/packages/module-yourmodule-x.x.x.json first. around line 35 you'll find:

```
"callback": {
  "path": null,
  "class": "Engine_Package_Installer_Module",
  "priority": 100
},
```

change that to:

```
"callback": {
  "path": "application/modules/Yourmodule/settings/install.php",
  "class": "Yourmodule_Installer",
  "priority": 100
},
```

now, when you run the installer, your install.php will be called.